# How to use a line break in JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have the text on my website appear from a .json file, and I want to have the line appear as:

Phone: 123-456-7890

Local: 012-35-6789

Instead I am getting:

Phone: 123-456-7890
Local: 012-35-6789

My code:

```
footer{
   "call_us": "Phone: {phone_number} \n Local: 012-345-6789"
}
```

Is there something besides \n I should be using?

Edit:

I am calling the JSON text to be displayed using the following code. I believe this is using Handlebars

```
{{#if settings.phone_number}}
                <strong>{{lang 'footer.call_us' phone_number=settings.phone_number}}</strong>
            {{/if}}
```

Full Code:

```
<article class="footer-info-col footer-info-col--small" data-section-type="storeInfo">
            <h5 class="footer-info-heading">{{lang 'footer.info'}}</h5>
            <address>{{nl2br settings.address}}</address>
            <script> var footer={
                "call_us": "Phone: {phone_number} \n Local: 012-345-6789"
            }
            for (var key in footer) {
                if (footer.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    console.log(footer[key]);
                }
            }</script>
            <!--{{#if settings.phone_number}}
                <strong>{{lang 'footer.call_us' phone_number=settings.phone_number}}</strong>-->
            {{/if}}
        </article>
```

Comment: You could replace all ocurrences of `\n` to a `<br>` tag when outputting to html or simply store as `<br>` instead of `\n`. I don't know if the second option is good.

Comment: @Phiter Is `<br>` meant to work in json? Others have suggested that, but that only displays as text for me. Am I doing something wrong if I just replace `\n` with `<br>`?

Comment: <br> is not json related, it's just html. And you can have html in your json values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by breaking the JSON line into two separate lines, and in the HTML file adding in the second call with a `<br>` in between the two. I would still love to know if there is a simple command that would do this in JSON, like `<br>` or `\n` but neither of those work for me.

JSON:

```
    "footer": {
    "call_us": "Phone: {phone_number}",
    "localc": "Local: 012-345-6789"
}
```

HTML:

```
{{#if settings.phone_number}}
                <strong>{{lang 'footer.call_us' phone_number=settings.phone_number}}</strong>
                <br><strong>{{lang 'footer.localc'}}</strong>
            {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 14):

**\r**

It's that simple. I've been trying to figure this out too for a mastodon bot using tracery.

If you use \r you'll get a carriage return.

Answer (score 3):

If you're outputting your `call_us` with PHP you can use PHP's `nl2br()` function: http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php

If you're outputting it with JS, you can use `yourvar.replace("\n", "<br />")`

otherwise use `<br />` instead of `\n` in your JSON.

Comment: I am outputting with javascript, although using `<br />` does not work, instead it is displaying that as text. When I use `\n` it does not appear as text, but it does not separate the lines.

Comment: This is how it is called in JS: 
 
                    {{#if settings.phone_number}}
                    <strong>{{lang 'footer.call_us' 
    phone_number=settings.phone_number}}</strong>
                {{/if}}

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the `\n` into an HTML break: `<br>`.
You can do this with the String replace method.

Comment: This does not work. That just displays `<br>` as text.

Comment: replace with <br/> not <br>

Answer (score 0):

```js
var footer={
   "call_us": "Phone: {phone_number} \n Local: 012-345-6789"
}
for (var key in footer) {
  if (footer.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(footer[key]);

  }
}
```

Comment: How would I implement this? Replace the place where the text is called with what you provided or replace the text in the json file?

Comment: Ok when you create you json object on the page instead of printing it directly use this function to print it

Comment: I am not having any luck with that, although it seems like it should work. I replaced the line where I was calling in the json code with what you provided, and surrounded that with `<script>` tags as it is an HTML document.

Comment: See the edit to my original post. That has the entire relevant area of the code. Is there really no symbol in JSON that performs the same function as `<br>` does in HTML? It seems like a line break should be simple.

Comment: add double quetos arrond local